# .htaccess Force PDF Download in Safari

Tags: .htaccess, safari, download

I want to force a PDF to download, rather than load in-browser.

I'm using the following code in my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

It works great, except in Safari.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.pdf$" requested_pdf=pdf
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_pdf
```

It appears to work fine even with safari on my tests here

Comment: That was too fast for me to accept the answer :). I'll accept it in 6 minutes.