# Force file download on iOS 7 and 8 with .htaccess

Tags: ios, .htaccess, download

I'm trying to force the download of .pdf and .mp4 files using this lines of code in my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mov|mp3|mp4|webm|pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

However, it doesn't work on iOS 7 and iOS8. I works **everywhere else**, but just not on iphones and ipads. What can i change to fix this? shouldn't this be enought to force the downloads?

thanks

**EDIT:**

I tried using, as mentioned on the answer that you pointed out, this lines of code:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.pdf$" requested_pdf=pdf
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_pdf
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.mp4$" requested_mp4=mp4
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_mp4
```

Still not working. And i'm using Chrome and Safari, not just mobile safari.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess Force PDF Download in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782892/htaccess-force-pdf-download-in-safari)

Comment: On iOS there is no public file system, so what do you expect iOS to do with the file?

Comment: i have some pdf that i'd like to download so that even if there's no nternet connection i can still be able to view them. Same for the videos. 
I tryed the answer mentioned above but it didn't work either, still open into the browser (both chrome for ios and safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS has no public file system, therefor you can not download any files in safari.
All you can do is open then in safari and them save them so an other application, like iBooks for PDF.

For example the iBooks bar in Safari:
[image]